# Custom file format read and write with Java

Tags: java, file, parsing

Using Java, I need to be able to read and write to a specific file with the following format:

```
rootConfig {
    limitDefinitions {
        limitDefinition(name:'sport', limit:3)
        limitDefinition(name:'news', limit:3)
    }
    blocks {
        when(rule ==~ /\/sport/.*/) {
            require(Session)
        }
        when(rule ==~ /\/news/.*/) {
            require(Session)
        }
    }
}
```

The current code base uses regular expressions to extract sections of code E.g. limitDefinitions, manipulate them and write then back. Although this works, it limiting as this file could change in the future. Does anyone know of an existing library that can make this easier?

"Note: I'm considering to create an object hierarchy mimicking the file structure with the idea to build the structure in code and a simple call to toString() on the parent object ("RootConfig") to generate the outputted file content. By representing each section of the file contents with an object this would make later expansions easier. The challenge however, lies in reading the file contents from an existing file to build up the object hierarchy."

Comment: It looks like it could be done with a simple parser.  But I don't know of any that will read that specific syntax.  What that config file from?

Comment: You could run a script in a language which support text parsing more naturally.

Comment: That looks an awful lot like a Groovy DSL.